# Json from two mysql tables in PHP require output in hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have Two Tables,

1 - Category

2 - Sub Category

```
 Category (table 1)
---------------
Cid    |   Name

1      |   Vegetable

2      |   Fruit


SubCategory  (table 2)
----------------
Cid  |  Sid | S_name

 1   |   1  | Carrot

 1   |   2  | Beans

 2   |  3   | Mango
```

I want results like that in Json:-

```
  -> Category found

       ->  Vegetable

            -> carrot

             -> beans

       ->  Fruit

             -> mango
```

I am using below code! Can anyone help me to correct my code & get output like that I mention above! i tried many times. but not get the solution! Please help me to get output like directory form. Thanks

```
`$srtResult = "SELECT * FROM `category` `c` LEFT JOIN `subcategory` `s` ON 
(`c`.`cid` = `s`.`cid`)";

 //Execute Qu**strong text**ery
    $result=mysql_query($srtResult);
   //Iterate Throught The Results

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ $count = $row['cid'];
 while($row['cid'] = $count)
 { $subcatitem[] = Array( "cid" => $row['cid'], "sid" =>$row['sid'],          
"sname" => $row['sc_name'] );
  }
  $json['category'][] = Array("category" => Array( "cid" => $row['cid'], 
"name" => $row['name'], "subcategory" => Array( $subcatitem))); 
  } 

  header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this be enough?

```
$srtResult = "SELECT * FROM `category` `c` LEFT JOIN `subcategory` `s` ON 
(`c`.`cid` = `s`.`cid`)";
$result = mysql_query($srtResult);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $json['category'][$row['name']] = $row['sc_name']; 
} 

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

**Edit:**

After more explanation in comments, the required PHP array structure (to give the expected JSON string) should look like:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => Category found in Database
    [Category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => vegetable
                    [Subcategory] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [cid] => 1
                                    [sid] => 1
                                    [sc_name] => carrot
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [cid] => 1
                                    [sid] => 2
                                    [sc_name] => beans
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Fruit
                    [Subcategory] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [cid] => 1
                                    [sid] => 1
                                    [sc_name] => Mango
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Picard, I tried this, But its show me;- mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line no 10.

Comment: _For SELECT, (...) mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error._ You must have an error in your query - `$srtResult`. Maybe the table names not should be not `subcategory` but`SubCategory`? You can check for errors by: `if (!$result) {  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); }`

Comment: Thanks Picard,

I want output like that in Json, Can you please guide me coding for that!

    {"success":1,"message":"Category found in Database","Category":
[{"id":"1","name":"vegetable","Subcategory":
[{"cid":"1", "sid":"1","sc_name":"carrot"},
{"cid":"1", "sid":"2","sc_name":"beans"}]},
{"id":"2","name":"Fruit","Subcategory":
[{"cid":"1", "sid":"1","sc_name":"Mango"}]}]}

Comment: I have updated my answer to display the PHP array that you'd need to build if you want the JSON like above.